# Novice Menu/SubMenu issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, post, menu

I am still new to ASP.NET web programming so hopefully someone can help me out.
I have a horizontal MainMenu and another horizontal SubMenu directly under it.

I am loading these from a database into a MenuCollection Session variable which is a Dictionary of the SubMenu and it's ParentId.

When the user clicks a MainMenu item I want to swap in and display the correct SubMenu.

When the `MainMenu.MenuItemClick` event happens the postback occurs and then I try to put the correct menu from the Dictionary into the SubMenu but it doesn't show.

Do I need another postback for the SubMenu to load or need to do some javascript?
Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Below is my code.  Thanks.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class RootMaster
  Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

  Private ReadOnly connection As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString

  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
      Session("MenuData") = GetMenuData()
      AddTopMenuItems(Session("MenuData"))
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Function GetMenuData() As DataTable
    Using con As New SqlConnection(connection)
      Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from MenuData", con)
      Dim dtMenuItems As New DataTable()
      Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

      sda.Fill(dtMenuItems)
      cmd.Dispose()
      sda.Dispose()

      Return dtMenuItems
    End Using
  End Function

  Private Sub AddTopMenuItems(menuData As DataTable)
    Dim view As DataView = Nothing
    Dim MenuDictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Menu)

    view = New DataView(menuData)
    view.RowFilter = "ParentId IS NULL"
    For Each row As DataRowView In view
      'Adding the menu item'
      If row("IsActive") Then
        Dim RowId As Integer = row("Id")
        Dim newMenuItem As New MenuItem(row("Text").ToString(), RowId.ToString())
        newMenuItem.NavigateUrl = row("NavigateUrl").ToString()
        MainMenu.Items.Add(newMenuItem)

        'Create all sub menus for each main menu item, add to dictionary'
        Dim SubM = CreateSubMenus(menuData, newMenuItem)
        If SubM.Items.Count > 0 Then
          MenuDictionary.Add(RowId, SubM)
        End If
      End If
    Next

    Session("MenuCollection") = MenuDictionary
    MainMenu.Items(0).Selected = True
    view = Nothing
  End Sub

  Private Function CreateSubMenus(menuData As DataTable, parentMenuItem As MenuItem) As Menu
    Dim view As DataView = Nothing
    Dim Result As New Menu

    view = New DataView(menuData)
    view.RowFilter = "ParentId=" & parentMenuItem.Value

    For Each row As DataRowView In view
      If row("IsActive") Then
        Dim newMenuItem As New MenuItem(row("Text").ToString(), row("Id").ToString())
        newMenuItem.NavigateUrl = row("NavigateUrl").ToString()
        Result.Items.Add(newMenuItem)
      End If
    Next

    Return Result
  End Function

  Protected Sub MainMenu_ItemClick(source As Object, e As MenuEventArgs) Handles MainMenu.MenuItemClick
    If Not Session("MenuCollection") Is Nothing Then
      Dim MenuDictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, Menu) = DirectCast(Session("MenuCollection"), Dictionary(Of Integer, Menu))

      If MenuDictionary.ContainsKey(e.Item.Value) Then
        SubMenu = MenuDictionary.Item(e.Item.Value)
      End If
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to do the redrawing of the sub menu on a PreRender event. So, for example:

```
Protected Sub MainMenu_ItemClick(source As Object, e As MenuEventArgs) Handles MainMenu.MenuItemClick
If Not Session("MenuCollection") Is Nothing Then
  Dim MenuDictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, Menu) = DirectCast(Session("MenuCollection"), Dictionary(Of Integer, Menu))

  If MenuDictionary.ContainsKey(e.Item.Value) Then
    SubMenu = MenuDictionary.Item(e.Item.Value)
  End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Might become:

```
Protected Sub MainMenu_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MainMenu.PreRender
If Not Session("MenuCollection") Is Nothing Then
   Dim MenuDictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, Menu) = DirectCast(Session("MenuCollection"), Dictionary(Of Integer, Menu))

        If MenuDictionary.ContainsKey(e.Item.Value) Then
        SubMenu = MenuDictionary.Item(e.Item.Value)
        End If
End If 
End Sub
```

If this isn't working then I'm afraid I'm not much help beyond that, just a thought though. I figure if your problem is you need another preload for the menu then using a prerender could maybe solve it.